# Dynamic optimization with linear interpolation for some parameters in GEKKO

Tags: python, gekko

This is a follow-up question from my previous post on linear interpolation while solving ODEs in GEKKO. Basically, I have a parameter `k` as a linear function of time, `k(t)`, like:

[image: k profile]

and I want to include this parameter to be automatically interpolated during ODE integration.

Below is the code for running the simulation:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

kt = np.array([0,0.2,0.45,0.75,1.0])
kv = np.array([0.5,1.0,0.2,1.2,1.0])

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
# include kt time points in m.time
m.time = np.concatenate((m.time, kt))
m.time = np.sort(m.time)
m.time = np.unique(m.time)

k = np.interp(m.time, kt, kv)
k = m.Param(value=k)

x = m.Var(value=0)
m.Equation(x.dt() == k)

m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=False)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(5,2.5))
plt.plot(kt,kv,'bo-',label='k data')
plt.plot(m.time,k.value,'rx-',label='k interp')
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'k-',label='x')
plt.plot(); plt.legend(); plt.grid()
##plt.tight_layout(); plt.savefig('p.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

My follow-up question is that I now want to calculate `k(t)`, i.e., optimization, to achieve some objective function.

So, I modified the above code to change `k` from `Param` to `MV` and switched to `IMODE = 6`.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

kt = np.array([0,0.2,0.45,0.75,1.0])
kv = np.array([0.5,1.0,0.2,1.2,1.0])

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
# include kt time points in m.time
m.time = np.concatenate((m.time, kt))
m.time = np.sort(m.time)
m.time = np.unique(m.time)

k = np.interp(m.time, kt, kv)
k = m.MV(value=k,lb = 0, ub = 2,fixed_initial=False)
k.STATUS = 1

x = m.Var(value=0)
m.Equation(x.dt() == k)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.Minimize(x)
m.solve(disp=False)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(5,2.5))
plt.plot(kt,kv,'bo-',label='k data')
plt.plot(m.time,k.value,'rx-',label='k interp')
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'k-',label='x')
plt.plot(); plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The thing is that the above code calculates `k` for 13 points corresponding to the length of m.time. However, I want the solver to calculate `k` for only 5 points corresponding to the original length of `kv`. The reason is that, in the actual problem, only 5 points are enough for optimziation, and so calculating 13 points is too expensive. This is a cartoon example, so the reason may not be obvious, but in the real problem, it is 15 points for `kv` vs 150 points for `m.time` (the ODE is very stiff), and so that is really important.

Another approach I tried is force `k` to have 5 points:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

kt = np.array([0,0.2,0.45,0.75,1.0])
kv = np.array([0.5,1.0,0.2,1.2,1.0])

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
k = m.MV(value=kv, lb = 0, ub = 2,fixed_initial=False)
k.STATUS = 1

x = m.Var(value=0)
m.Equation(x.dt() == k)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.Minimize(x)
m.solve(disp=False)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(5,2.5))
plt.plot(kt,kv,'bo-',label='k data')
plt.plot(m.time,k.value,'rx-',label='k interp')
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'k-',label='x')
plt.plot(); plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

But got an error: Data arrays must have the same length, and match time discretization in dynamic problems, which is understandable.

Really appreciate if someone could help solve this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `m.options.MV_STEP_HOR` to adjust from the default value of 1 (make a move every step) to a higher value, such as 4 to make a manipulated variable move every 4 steps. To keep the same slope in that interval, define a new manipulated variable `ks` as the slope and `k` as a variable.

```py
k = m.Var(lb=0, ub=2, fixed_initial=False)
ks = m.MV(value=0,lb=-10,ub=10); ks.STATUS=1
m.Equation(k.dt()==ks)
```

The lower `lb` and upper `ub` bounds on `ks` set the minimum and maximum rate of change of `k`. The objective function is modified to make the result more interesting. The blue dashed is the slope `ks` and the red line is `k`. The slope of `k` changes when `ks` changes every 4 time points. There are 10 time steps in this problem so the changes occur at `t=0`, `t=0.4`, `t=0.8` with `0.1` time intervals.

```py
m.Minimize((x-0.5)**2)
```

[image: slope results]

Here is the full script:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
k = m.Var(lb=0, ub=2, fixed_initial=False)
ks = m.MV(value=0,lb=-10,ub=10); ks.STATUS=1
m.Equation(k.dt()==ks)

x = m.Var(value=0)
m.Equation(x.dt() == k)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.MV_STEP_HOR=4

m.Minimize((x-0.5)**2)
m.solve(disp=False)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(5,2.5))
plt.step(m.time,ks.value,'b:',label='ks')
plt.plot(m.time,k.value,'rx-',label='k')
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'k-',label='x')
plt.plot(); plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much John. Things work perfectly. I will remember this trick. By the way, I have one quick question to clarify. It seems like solving ODE in GEKKO always relies on the time step (m.time) that we provided in some ways. If I understand correctly, the solver does not do adaptive time stepping (like MATLAB's ode15s, for example), is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. It doesn't use adaptive time-stepping unless it fails to converge when using `IMODE=7`. You may want to use `m.logspace()` instead of `m.linspace()` to generate the time-steps if you are worried about accuracy of a stiff system. A grid independent study usually involves adding additional time points to confirm that the solution does not change with the additional points.